# expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant

Tags: c++, arduino

I give up. Nor google answers me or the documentation. Whats wrong in here?

> " In file included from x.cpp:7:
>   /Users/user/Dropbox/Projects/Arduino/libraries/Range/Range.h:27:
>   error: expected identifier before numeric constant
>   /Users/user/Dropbox/Projects/Arduino/libraries/Range/Range.h:27:
>   error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant "

```
//
//  Range.h
//  Handles range to ground and altitude
//
//  Created by x on 2013-03-27.
//
//

#ifndef RANGE_H_
#define RANGE_H_

#include "NewPing.h"

#define BOTTOM_RF_PIN       5
#define BOTTOM_RF_ECHO_PIN  10
#define BOTTOM_RF_MAX       200


class Range {
public:
    Range();
    void init();
    float toGround();
    float toCeiling();
    float altitude();
private:
    NewPing bottomRF(BOTTOM_RF_PIN, BOTTOM_RF_ECHO_PIN, BOTTOM_RF_MAX);

};

#endif /* RANGE_H_ */
```

Comment: I think he's trying to declare a variable of type NewPing. You have to initialize the variable in Range() : bottomRF( constants ) { } instead. It's a good place for compilers to noob-check for all-literals or missing types in parameters and help them out with a less useless error message, but who cares about C++, right (for offended: it's irony)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of

`NewPing bottomRF(BOTTOM_RF_PIN, BOTTOM_RF_ECHO_PIN, BOTTOM_RF_MAX);`

Try

`NewPing bottomRF(int, int, int);`

Reason: You cannot declare a function to take literals. Only types. `int` is a type, 5 10 and 200 are literals.

Comment: I don't think he was trying to declare a function.  I think he was trying to call a constructor.  Which he still can't do.

Comment: .cpp I have int Range::toCeiling(){return bottomRF.ping_cm();} but I get an error that In member function 'float Range::toCeiling()': does not have class type. Do you know why?

Comment: @socr19991293 Either bottomRF is intended to be a function, and you meant to write `bottomRF().ping_cm()` - OR - bottomRF is intended to be a variable, but you declared it as a function.

Comment: It is intented to be a variable. How can I declare it as a variable?

Comment: @socr19991293: Try Tushar's answer. Basically, you can't instantiate/construct an object during class declaration, but you can do it in other places.

Answer (score 3):

In case `bottomRF` is a data member, and not a function, and you are trying to instantiate it in the class declaration:

You cannot instantiate class-type items in the class declaration. A good place to do so is in the constructor initialization list.

```
public:
    Range() :bottomRF(BOTTOM_RF_PIN, BOTTOM_RF_ECHO_PIN, BOTTOM_RF_MAX) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't you need to specify the type of parameters? e.g.

```
NewPing bottomRF(int a1 = BOTTOM_RF_PIN, int a2= BOTTOM_RF_ECHO_PIN, int a3 = BOTTOM_RF_MAX);
```